# Oracle start up tools.. What do I need?

Tags: oracle, database

So I am totally new to Oracle, I am changing over from SQL Server, I wanted to ask you guys what I need to start up, which is the best IDE to work with?? What other software do I need to start writing Oracle DBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Express Edition, and Oracle's own SQL Developer tool.

In some circumstances you might benefit from Instant Client too, also from Oracle.